# scaling background Image in IE

Tags: html

so, I got a bit of a problem here, I implemented my background image with this code

```
  <div style="
            background: url(http://oi57.tinypic.com/2wlyhd5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;    
            background-size:cover;
            width:100%; 
            position:fixed;
            height:100%;
            z-index:-1;">               
        </div>
```

problem is, when I scroll out in IE the image doesn't scale, same when zooming in, it works in the other browsers

Comment: it's version 11 of IE

Comment: What do you mean by scale? Increasing the size?

Comment: What do you mean by 'scroll out' and 'zooming in'? How would zooming the viewport change the size of the div?

Comment: I mean that if I scroll into the page with strg + mousewheel, the Image doesn't stay in full resolution on the screen, it shrinks/gets bigger together with the rest, but I want the image to stay the same size all the time, no matter how far you zoom in/out of the website

Comment: Can you check what Browser Mode and Document Mode you are in by pressing F12

Answer (score 2):

As far as Internet Explorer is concerned you can only use **Background Size** from IE9+, luckily there's a workaround.

[Background Size Polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill#readme)

```
.selector { 
  background-size: cover;
  /* The url is relative to the document, not to the css file! */
  /* Prefer absolute urls to avoid confusion. */
  -ms-behavior: url(/backgroundsize.min.htc);
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP's issue is with applying the background-size itself - rather how the browser displays it upon zooming.